# Error while installing pillow on pyzo

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-imaging-library, pyzo

I'm trying to install PIL on pyzo2014a but it give an error:

> TypeError: `__call__()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'"

Here is the complete report:

```
C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py run on 01/25/17 21:50:00
Downloading/unpacking pillow
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/
URLs to search for versions for pillow:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/
Skipping link  https://pypi.python.org/packages/00/15/e776f42afb6d79f27710aded08fd50998174f772621f1cda5d44701be1ed/Pillow-2.1.0-py2.6-win32.egg#md5=0a85404ffb50fff762615a47e6d363e9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/); unknown archive format: .egg

Ignoring link                https://pypi.python.org/packages/7b/11/1d49e73f946234604325f1aafdc2781d02963ea83d    cdceda595a62d978f0/Pillow-3.1.0.rc1.zip#md5=df5113cb2e0bc130f3aeb5c543829f18       (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/), version 3.1.0.rc1 is a pre-release     (use --pre to allow).
Ignoring link   https://pypi.python.org/packages/91/a8/8ea7bbf6e950531509063b08b30595940f8aef4969    becfdb2b81f2941b2d/Pillow-3.1.0- rc1.tar.gz#md5=e37ac34db7259c95b513939595ad1e7c (from  https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/), version 3.1.0-rc1 is a pre-release (use  --pre to allow).
Ignoring link  https://pypi.python.org/packages/99/c7/2b01d25cf2e66edd5fbcbf372dae68a9a079a17a14c6b6fadc5df69a930f/Pillow-3.1.0rc1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=ff9da8cb052ff99bbf3b50a15d3cc7b4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/), version 3.1.0rc1 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
Using version 4.0.0 (newest of versions: 4.0.0, 3.4.2, 3.4.2, 3.4.1, 3.4.1, 3.4.0, 3.4.0, 3.3.3, 3.3.3, 3.3.2, 3.3.2, 3.3.1, 3.3.1, 3.3.0, 3.3.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.0, 3.1.2, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.0, 2.9.0, 2.9.0, 2.9.0, 2.8.2, 2.8.2, 2.8.2, 2.8.1, 2.8.1, 2.8.1, 2.8.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.0, 2.7.0, 2.7.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.2, 2.6.2, 2.6.2, 2.6.1, 2.6.1, 2.6.1, 2.6.0, 2.6.0, 2.6.0, 2.5.3, 2.5.3, 2.5.2, 2.5.2, 2.5.1, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.5.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.0, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.0, 1.7.8, 1.7.7, 1.7.6, 1.7.6, 1.7.5, 1.7.4, 1.7.3, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0)
Downloading from URL  https://pypi.python.org/packages/8d/80/eca7a2d1a3c2dafb960f32f844d570de988e609f5fd17de92e1cf6a01b0a/Pillow-4.0.0.tar.gz#md5=d5af224b0fa2c66dacc9814785fef9e7 (from  https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/)
Cleaning up...
Removing temporary dir C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Acer...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,  bundle=self.bundle)
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
req_to_install.run_egg_info()
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 292, in run_egg_info
logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.setup_py, self.name))
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 265, in setup_py
import setuptools
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
import setuptools.version
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
import pkg_resources
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
import packaging.requirements
File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\packaging\requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
 MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
 TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

What does this mean?

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: In fact I use the module tkinter on pyzo2014a and I need to install pillow in order to put a picture in the background of my canvas. And to do that, I have used the syntax 'pip install pillow' written on my pyzo shell.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the program is trying to build Pillow from source and failing. On Windows programs are often distributed in binary (pre-built) form so the whole build process can be avoided.

Pyzo comes with two tools for installing pacakges. Pip which builds from source, and Conda which installs binaries.

To install Pillow using Conda, open the program `cmd` and run

```
C:\Pyzo2014\Scripts\conda.exe install Pillow
```

Comment: I have tried this handling and it gives the same report (the same error). I tried this several times and now my computer display : "Cette application ne peut pas s'exécuter sur votre PC"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your aid but the best solution is : download an upper version. For my part I have downloaded Pyzo2016 (on http://www.pyzo.org/start.html#quickstart ), then I have installed : it and 'Python environment'. And by using the syntax :

```
conda install pillow
```

written on my shell, I have installed the modul PIL and it works very well !!